# Engine started to consume oil

Tags: oil, oil-leak, oil-consumption

My engine used to leak due to seal fail 6 months ago. it was a problem caused by over level oil. Now all leaks are fixed but there is still a gradual oil consumption over mileage.

For the last 3 months here are my notes:

- About 1 litre or less per every 1000km.
- I use 10w30 oil as per user-manual while weather reaches 45C and above where I live.
- There are oil vapors in the intake from the PCV.
- I was changing the sparkplugs and there were wet oil over them.
- I took the car for two continuous 400km ride per each then checked the oil there were no consumption, consumption -I think- happens between separate travels regardless trip mileage!
- No sign of smoke while driving. however, every time I start the engine when cold there is a small puff of thin white smoke that goes away. I live in a hot weather BTW.
- No highly-noticeable lack of performance / gas consumption / over heating for such a high mileage condition as mine.

I was consulting a mechanic around here, he confirmed that I can use it but it needs a complete rebuild to be fixed!

Could these symptoms above indicated a 'piston oil rings wear' or 'valve stem seals wear' or something else? and how long can I depend on my motor before it could get into a serious problem?

Answer (score 1):

Before you go crazy rebuilding the engine, you need to look at the PCV system to ensure the valve is functioning properly. If it's drawing too much vacuum (sucking too much), it can draw oil which sounds about like the amount you're talking about. If you're not seeing blue smoke (white smoke as you describe at this point is not important ... this is water vapor from a cold vehicle which is normal), then the consumption is a very small amount over time. I'd suggest even on your short trip it was consuming oil, but not as much. It could be exacerbated by stop and go driving like you'd see in a city. A new PCV is a few dollars in most cases. If it continues, an oil catch can may be necessary to stop the oil loss (if that indeed is what the issue is).

Comment: thank you for the reply.
I believe that it could be a PCV problem but I'm afraid it is due too a blowby caused by piston oilrings.

my engine have a PCV orifice not a valve, I'll consider checking the whole system and the catchcan was in my mind. would it help?
BTW a check-engine light come and go randomly!